# Rendering NSView to image: cacheDisplayInRect draws transparent areas differently from usual drawRect call

Tags: cocoa, nsview, drawrect, nsimage, image-capture

**Greetings!** I have a problem and Googling brought no results...

I implemented the drawRect method for my NSView (subclass) to draw some shadows and semi-transparent fills. Everything looks great! But now I need to create an NSImage from my NSView (make snapshot) for drag&drop purposes.

It works, but draws in some different manner: darker and not so contrast as should be.
**Why? Maybe because of NSGraphicContext different options? Need help and/or advice!**

Here is the code for getting NSImage from NSView:

```
- (NSImage *)makeImageSnapshot {

    NSSize imgSize = self.bounds.size;

    NSBitmapImageRep * bir = [self bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:[self bounds]];
    [bir setSize:imgSize];

    [self cacheDisplayInRect:[self bounds] toBitmapImageRep:bir];

    NSImage* image = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:imgSize] autorelease];
    [image addRepresentation:bir];

    return image;
}
```

And here are the images to compare visually:

1. Normal - drawn by drawRect usual call: http://cl.ly/image/213C1Y1V0v2H
2. Bad - captured into NSImage: http://cl.ly/image/183q442S2J14

Thought the difference might seem very small, believe me - it is obvious while working with application. I don't undertand why that is happening. And hope someone can help...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your links are dead. Can you please bring back those images? Attaching them to the question itself would probably be best. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I've deleted them permanently by mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the transparency problem is caused by not having other things to blend it against when it's cached on its own.

Try -dataWithPDFInsideRect: or -dataWithEPSInsideRect: and get your image reps from there.

Comment: Thanks, Joshua! The problem is that I render this image off-the-screen and both of this methods produce invalid image, besides they work slowly. All the other ways I know to create NSView snapshot don't preserve transparency. It looks like I will have to correct the drawRect for this case.

Comment: A point to note:`dataWithPDFInsideRect` is incredibly slow (https://openradar.appspot.com/21666422) This is still the case in macOS 11.4 (Big Sur)